# CanDeactivate Guard Not Triggering for Home Hyperlink in Microfrontend Architecture

Tags: angular, angularjs, frontend, micro-frontend, candeactivate

I'm encountering an issue with the canDeactivate guard in my Angular application built with a microfrontend architecture. Here's the problem:

Problem Description:
When navigating using the "Home" hyperlink Home, the canDeactivate guard is not being triggered. It's worth noting that the "Home" page does not exist within my project's route configuration. My project is accessible via the route localhost:4200/example, and all declared routes within my project work seamlessly with the canDeactivate guard. However, the guard fails to detect navigation triggered by the "Home" hyperlink.

Additional Context:

The application is structured using microfrontends, with my project being one of them, built using Angular and .NET.
The "Home" page is hosted in a different microfrontend project.
Other routes declared within my project correctly trigger the canDeactivate guard when navigating away.
Request for Assistance:
I'm seeking advice or solutions to ensure that the canDeactivate guard correctly handles navigation triggered by the "Home" hyperlink. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Please include some additional useful context for your question e.g.

What version of Angular are you using?
What is the canDeactivate guard and how are you using it?
Can you share some of the code related to your home link/canDeactivate guard?